# newbie: need some explanation on this Django url

Tags: python, django, django-urls

During url mapping in the tutorial I came across this code:

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category')
```

I do understand a few things except this part:

```
(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)
```

I saw (`?P<...` before, but I've never seen `[\w\-]+)` before and I can't find explanations on the internet.

Hopefully you can help me out ;)

Answer (score 4):

`[\w-]+` means "one or more word-characters or dashes".

"Word-characters" are letters (lower- and upper-case), digits, and underscores.

The square brackets enclose a set of characters (explicit, or implied by escape sequences such as `\w`).  The dash, if it's part of the set, must be at the end, just before the close-bracket (otherwise it indicates a **range**, e.g, `[a-c]` means "a, b, or c").

The `+` postfix means "one or more" as always in regular expressions.

Enclosing a part (say "..." as a placeholder) of the patter in a `(?P<name>...)` construct means that the part matched by that pattern (in RE terms called a **group**) can be accessed with the symbolic name you've just specified (**unnamed** groups, make by simple parentheses as in `(...)`, can only be accessed by number, from left to right).

Comment: @NomadProgrammer, always glad to help, and I hope you'll **accept** the answer (click on the checkmark-shaped outline to its left) once enough time has passed since when you asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

`(?P<category_name_slug>[\w \ -]+)` 
Means you are expecting a one or more words or dashes that will be mapped to `category_name_slug` variable and pass it into your view.

So in your view, you will have something like this:

```
 def yourView(self,request,category_name_slug):
     // here you can use category_name_slug
```

Answer (score 1):

You will find every combination in the Python Regex doc pages:

[Python Version 2.7.9: 7.2. re - Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

I hope this help.